# Run PHP script when button is clicked without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a problem with PHP and JavaScript.

**Goal**: A .php script should be executed when the event listener of the HTML button in the .js file is called **without** reloading the page.

**Expected result**: When the button is clicked, the PHP script gets executed. In my case, a file from a URL will be downloaded to the server.

**Actual result**: I don't know how to call the PHP script from the JavaScript file.

I tried using AJAX, but nothing really worked out. Also I didn't know where exactly to put the library reference for JQuery.

I also tried to use a form, and inside of it an input (type="submit"), but when this calls the PHP function, it refreshes the page and everything on the page which was displaying client side is gone.

The HTML button:

```
<button type="button" class="button" id="btnsubmit">Submit</button>
<img class="image" id="someimage">
```

The JavaScript event listener (I have the button and image already assigned to a var):

```
btnsubmit.addEventListener("click", () => {
    someimage.src = "directory/downloadedimg.png";
});
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php
    $path = 'https://somewebsite.com/imagetodownload.png';
    $dir = 'directory/downloadedimg.png';
    
    $content = file_get_contents($path);
    $fp = fopen($dir, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

*So in general, I want to do as follows when the button gets clicked:*

1. Download the image from the URL to my server using PHP
2. Display the image **from the server** (not from the URL, I know it's possible, but for my use I need it to be from the server) in an HTML image using JavaScript

I tried the answer of @Abhishek and figured the problem now lies in my php file. It always gives me an internal server error.
Do you spot any error in this code to upload the image from the $path (it's a URL) to my server (serverdirectorypath is $image_url):

```
<?php
$params = $_POST['data'];
$path = $params['path'];
$image_url = $params['image-url'];
    
$content = file_get_contents($path);
$fp = fopen($image_url, "w");
fwrite($fp, $content);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: What's your question? Please see [ask], then revise to be more specific about what's going wrong.

Comment: Just by the tittle, what if a user click 100 times on the button, your server will crash!

Comment: Just FYI, the image src in the DOM will be immediately updated, and will probably result in 404 not found, because your download/save will still be in progress. What you want to do is an [async Fetch call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) where your JS code waits for the download to conclude before updating the image reference in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following things.

1. Add jquery in head/bottom section of your page like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2. Use jquery AJAX and call your php script like below

```
        $("#button-id").on('click',function(){
            var data = {"image-url" : "directory/downloadedimg.png","path" : "https://somewebsite.com/imagetodownload.png"};
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: "{hostname}/test.php",
              data: data,
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(resultData) { alert("success"); }
           });
        });
```

3. In your php script ex- test.php, use code like below to get post params.

```
    $params = $_POST['data'];
    $path = $params['path'];
    $image_url = $params['image-url'];
```

and do the business operation, you want to do in this.

Comment: Where do I put step 2? Into the event listener in the js file or in the HTML file?

Comment: Apparently it also doesn't alert the "success". even if I simplify the PHP file so that there can't be an error (just the post params), it doesn't alert. Any idea why?

Comment: You can create new html or php file with name ex- demo.php and use step 1 and step 2 in there. Also put html button on same file. <button type="button" class="button" id="btnsubmit">Submit</button>
<img class="image" id="someimage">

Answer (score -1):

No need another library, you can do this with vanillaJs. 
Your misunderstanding come from : "how to call php with Js and get returned value" 
Start here you have an exemple: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp
Once you will be able to call your PHP script you will have done 70% of your target

Comment: Please add code to solve the problem. If that (hm, w3schools ...) URL is unavailable this answer is of no use to anyone. Thanks